# Phone number validation with plus sign optional

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

How can i validate a phone number with plus sign optional only at the beginning and after that any number of digits with number only.

I tried this:-

```
/^\+(?:[\d]*)$/
```

How will be the modification

Comment: The regex is `^\+?\d+$`. In HTML `pattern` attribute, it looks like `pattern="\+?\d+"`. If you need to limit the number of digits to a specific amount replace `\d+` with `\d{n}` where `n` is the exact number of digits you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/^\+?(?:[\d]*)$/
```

The questionmark tells that the plus sign can be there or not. However, your expression can be optimized quite a bit:

```
/^\+?\d+$/
```

I changed the `*` to a `+` as the expression would match just a plus sign. `\d*` suggests that it should match 0 or more digits.

Here's a [**demo on Regexr**](http://regexr.com/3apsm).

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary stuff in there, the shortened version would be `/^\+?\d*$/`.

Answer (score -1):

Expression for plus, hyphen and numbers in a phone number

```txt
^\+?\d+-?[0-9]+-?[0-9]+$
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. - Please give a little explanation to your example.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.